# Overwritting characters from a file in Python

Tags: python

I want to change some text in a file i have, but I can't find a proper way to delete a character from a file with python. Is it possible?
For example I have a file which looks alot like this:

```
Marry has 10 carrots
Bob has 15 apples
Tom has 4 bananas
```

Now I want to change the numbers in the file, or even the fruits.
I can read just the numbers but I can't remove them or overwrite them.

Comment: Read the file, parse the information, change the information, and write out the data to the file in the same format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) with `inplace=True` to modify the file content:

```
import fileinput
import sys
for line in fileinput.input("test.txt",inplace=True):
    # replaces all occurrences of apples in each line with oranges
    sys.stdout.write(line.replace("apples","oranges"))
```

Input:

```
Marry has 10 carrots
Bob has 15 apples
Tom has 4 bananas
```

Output:

```
Marry has 10 carrots
Bob has 15 oranges
Tom has 4 bananas
```

Use re to avoid matching substrings:

```
import fileinput
import sys
import re
# use word boundaries so we only match "apples"  
r = re.compile(r"\bapples\b")
for line in fileinput.input("test.txt",inplace=True):
    # will write the line as is or replace apples with oranges and write
    sys.stdout.write(r.sub("oranges",line))
```

To remove all the last words:

```
import fileinput
import sys
for line in fileinput.input("test.txt",inplace=True):
    # split on the last whitespace and write everything up to that
    sys.stdout.write("{}\n".format(line.rsplit(None, 1)[0]))
```

Output:

```
Marry has 10
Bob has 15
Tom has 4
```

You can also use a [tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) to write the updated lines to using any of the logic above, then use [shutil.move](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) to replace the original file:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from shutil import move

with open("test.txt") as f, NamedTemporaryFile("w",dir=".", delete=False) as temp:
    for line in f:
        temp.write("{}\n".format(line.rsplit(None, 1)[0]))

# replace original file with updated content
move(temp.name,"test.txt")
```

You need to pass `dir="."` and `delete=False` so the file file won't be deleted when we exit the with and we can access the file with the `.name` attribute to pass to shutil.

Comment: Is it possible to just delete the fruit?

Comment: @Singularity,  you mean all the last words?

Comment: Or just one? Or can I delete everything after a certain character like after the number?
To delete one I can simply write `sys.stdout.write(line.replace("apples","")`

Comment: can you explain your code a little I am not familiar with the sys library

Comment: @Singularity I find the rather implicit redirection of stdout to be very odd; it seems error prone.  What is its duration?  It looks to be permanent? Should your code finish with something like `sys.stdout=sys.__stdout__`?

Comment: @Alan, I have no idea what you just asked, duration of what, what is implicit? What is permanent?

Comment: How would I delete all numbers with stdout?

Comment: @Singularity, `re.compile("\d+")`

Comment: Can I also remove all words that start with a certain character, like all words that start with a "B"?

Comment: @Singularity, you can do a million different things, you could `" ".join([word for word in line.split() if not word.startswith("B")])`

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham, Thank you that was exactly what I was looking for.