# Filter list of tuples to removes lists with all odd number or sum less than 80

Tags: python, math, text-files

I have a text file with a bunch of tuples in it.  I want to filter the list so that if all numbers are odd, or if the sum of the numbers is less than 80, it will be removed.  How can I parse the lists and do this filtering?

Input:

```
(1, 3, 14, 38, 31)
(2, 3, 17, 32, 39)
(7, 9, 11, 12, 16)
(12, 13, 14, 16, 17)
(14, 16, 18, 38, 40)
(15, 23, 27, 31, 39)
```

Output:

```
(1, 3, 14, 38, 31)
(2, 3, 17, 32, 39)
(14, 16, 18, 38, 40)
```

Comment: Those are tuples not lists.

Comment: You should at least try to solve it yourself first before asking for a direct solution.

Comment: @ronakg i've been trying to work on this myself for a week but i honestly didn't even know where to begin, sorry if i bothered you but i tried, just not very good at coding, even at the easy stuff :\

Comment: This question seems better suited for doMyHomeworkForMePlease.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Algo:**

1. Read Input file and get lines
2. Iterate every line from the lines by `for loop`
3. eval line from string format to tuple fromat by `ast`
4. check sum is less then 80 or not , if yes then continue to next line.
5. check if all numbers from the line are odd or not.
6. add to result list.
7. Write result to output file.

**Code:**

```
from ast import literal_eval


with open("input.txt") as fp, open("output.txt", "wb") as out:
    result = []
    for line in fp:
        tup = literal_eval(line.rstrip())
        if not all(ii % 2 for ii in tup) and sum(tup) >= 80:
            out.write(line)
```

**Output file:**

```
(1, 3, 14, 38, 31)
(2, 3, 17, 32, 39)
(14, 16, 18, 38, 40)
```

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham: output not wrong after editing.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham: I changes `sum(tup) >=  80` in if condition. Can you review it?

Comment: good answer ;) you can use one `with` for in-file and the out-file

Comment: As @Kasra states - you can do a read/write line by line - you don't really need to build a list, then write from that...

Comment: @VivekSable, yes sorry should have been  >, you don't need to call readlines unless you want a list and using `[]` with any means the list of values is built regardless so you lost the advantage of short circuiting

Comment: @dubz, to change you original file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481308/overwritting-characters-from-a-file-in-python/30481339#30481339

Answer (score 1):

Here is it:

```
from ast import literal_eval


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("f.txt", 'r+') as f:
        s = f.read()

    with open("file.txt", 'w+') as f1:
        for x in s.split("\n"):
            if len(x) == 0:
                continue
            l = literal_eval(x)
            flt = [y for y in l if y % 2 == 0]
            if len(flt) == 0 or sum(l) < 80:
                continue
            print(x)
            f1.write("%s\n" % x)
```

**Output:**

```
(1, 3, 14, 38, 31)
(2, 3, 17, 32, 39)
(14, 16, 18, 38, 40)
```